# Second signer don´t receive the email notification

Tags: typescript, docusignapi

I made a `DocuSign` integration where I have two signers. The first one must sign using the embedded signing (this is working fine) and the other must sign by receiving an email notification. But after the first signer signs the document, the second signer didn´t receive the email notification to sign. I´m thinking that the process to send the email notification to the second signer is automatic.
Is that right? Or I have to send the email notification manually?
The flow to create this process is: 1-Create the envelop adding two signers, 2-Get the recipient view and open this to the first signer.

The `TypeScript` code:

```typescript
async uploadDocs(

    contract1File: Buffer,
    contract2File: Buffer,
    reference: string,
    signers: ISigner[],
  ): Promise<string> {
    const accountInfo = await this.getAccountInfo();
    console.log(accountInfo);
    
    const envelopeId = await this.createEnvelope(
      accountInfo,
      contract1File,
      contract2File,
      reference,
      signers,
    );
    
    const linkSign = await this.createRecipient(
      accountInfo,
      envelopeId,
      signers,
    );
    
    return linkSign;
}

  private async createRecipient(
    accountInfo: { accountId: string; baseUri: string },
    envelopeId: string,
    signers: ISigner[],
  ) {
    const recipientView: DsRecipientView = {
      returnUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/contact#summary',
      authenticationMethod: 'none',
      email: signers[0].email,
      userName: signers[0].name,
      clientUserId: signers[0].id,
    };
    const url = `${accountInfo.baseUri}/restapi/v2.1/accounts/${accountInfo.accountId}/envelopes/${envelopeId}/views/recipient`;
    const headers = {
      ...this.header,
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    };
    try {
      const respRecipient = await axios.post(url, recipientView, {
        headers,
      });
      console.log('respRecipient:', respRecipient.data);
      return respRecipient.data.url;
    } catch (err) {
      this.loggerService.error(`Error creating recipient: ${err.message}`);
      console.log(err);
    }
    return undefined;
  }

  private async createEnvelope(
    accountInfo: { accountId: string; baseUri: string },
    contract1File: Buffer,
    contract2File: Buffer,
    reference: string,
    signers: ISigner[],
  ): Promise<string> {
    const envelope = {
      emailSubject: 'CONTRATOS AVERA',
      documents: [],
      recipients: {
        signers: [],
      },
      status: 'sent',
    };
    const dsDocument1: DsDocument = {
      documentBase64: Buffer.from(contract1File).toString('base64'),
      documentId: '1',
      fileExtension: 'docx',
      name: reference,
    };
    envelope.documents.push(dsDocument1);
    const dsDocument2: DsDocument = {
      documentBase64: Buffer.from(contract2File).toString('base64'),
      documentId: '2',
      fileExtension: 'docx',
      name: reference,
    };
    envelope.documents.push(dsDocument2);

    const dsSigner1 = this.addSigner(signers[0], '1');
    envelope.recipients.signers.push(dsSigner1);
    const dsSigner2 = this.addSigner(signers[1], '2');
    envelope.recipients.signers.push(dsSigner2);

    const url = `${accountInfo.baseUri}/restapi/v2.1/accounts/${accountInfo.accountId}/envelopes`;
    const headers = {
      ...this.header,
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    };
    try {
      const respEnvelope = await axios.post(url, envelope, {
        headers,
      });
      console.log('respEnvelop:', respEnvelope.data);
      return respEnvelope.data.envelopeId;
    } catch (err) {
      this.loggerService.error(`Error creating envelop: ${err.message}`);
    }
    return undefined;
  }

  private addSigner(signer: ISigner, orderSign: string) {
    const dsSignPosition: DsSignPosition = {
      anchorString: `/sn${orderSign}/`,
      anchorUnits: 'pixels',
      anchorXOffset: '20',
      anchorYOffset: '10',
    };
    const dsFullNamePosition: DsSignPosition = {
      anchorString: `/fn${orderSign}/`,
      anchorUnits: 'pixels',
      anchorXOffset: '20',
      anchorYOffset: '10',
    };
    const dsSignTab: DsSignTab = {
      signHereTabs: [dsSignPosition],
      fullNameTabs: [dsFullNamePosition],
    };
    const dsSigner: DsSigner = {
      email: signer.email,
      name: signer.name,
      recipientId: orderSign,
      routingOrder: orderSign,
      clientUserId: signer.id,
      tabs: dsSignTab,
    };
    return dsSigner;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be setting clientUserId for the second signer but without your code is impossible to say what could be wrong. Can you post your create envelope json request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the clientUserId property. To send by email we can`t pass this.